# GET statuses/:id/retweeted_by returns which 100 users

Tags: twitter

The API says it only returns up to 100 users.

Does it return the first hundred, or the latest hundred retweeters? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The [retweeted_by API](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1/get/statuses/%3aid/retweeted_by) returns **the most recent** retweeters.

The are ordered by retweet date - most recent being first.

It is limited to 100 per page, but may return fewer than that (if someone has deleted their retweet, for example).

Comment: Thanks for giving light on this Terence!